# Is this an acceptable way to create +/-5V from +/-12V?

Tags: power-supply, power, ldo

The TLV76750 is a 5 V fixed-voltage LDO. I plan to use it to create ±5 V from ±12 V. Is there any caveat in hooking two of them up as shown below? The setup at the top is the standard configuration.

No need to comment on the large voltage drop from 12 V to 5 V causing considerable power dissipation.

[image]

---

**Edited to add** that the above circuit won't work (thanks to everyone for your comments). I can make it work though with two independent, galvanically isolated AC supplies, used as follows:

[image]

---

**Edited to add** The LTSpice simulation showing the concept of galvanic isolation or floating power supplies:

[image]

---

**Now including the transformers** and just for the fun of it, with opposite polarity of them. The result on the outputs is the same as shown in the diagram above:

[image]

Comment: The negative one won’t work. You need a regulator for negative voltages for that.

Comment: No explanation why you think or *know* that it won't work?

Comment: See below. Better yet, simulate it and find out yourself.

Comment: OP, not sure what your goal is, here. Your question shows a 'solution' of a 'negative' regulator wired with Vout to ground and its COM terminal used as a -5V current sink. People tell you it won't work but you claim it will regardless, so I don't know why you asked for technical proof to ignore. Your fault is seeing regulators as Magic Voltage Boxes then stackinh them as if they are batteries. Actually, they're made out of transistors and have specific requirements for operation. Read the datasheet, understand the regulator's internal circuit, all there. Or build it and watch it not work.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me. The galvanically isolated solution will work. Have you actually read my complete post? The key is the *galvanic* isolation.

Comment: Isolated power supplies won’t help, with a positive regulator you will get get Vin-5 out, which is useless as a regulator. Get yourself a negative one like 7905 and be done with it.

Comment: I will stop fighting over this. I *know* that it works.

Comment: diodes do not provide galvanic isolation

Comment: OK, I give this ONE more try. Take two galvanically isolated bench supplies (the secondary sides not earthed) and stack up the outputs similar to my second diagram above and the two voltages will add up. These are two floating supplies that are interconnected. I don't care about the old school noisy 79(L)05. I will now go with the LT1964 anyways. Sure, I should have thought more about the circuit in my initial question. But I know that the solution in the second diagram works.

Comment: @Hansel The suggestion of the 7905 was just a suggestion. You're welcome to use any negative voltage regulator you like.

Comment: @All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (CoC) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments & other text were deleted / edited. [Polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed in comments - with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*. Don't answer the question in comments. Also please check especially that a comment still complies with the CoC, if it includes the words "you" or "your". Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. What you're calling "-5 V" would actually be +5 volts with respect to the -12 volt rail, i.e. -7 volts. And it would only be able to *source* current into a load returned to a lower voltage; linear regulators can't generally *sink* current without either losing regulation or being damaged.

The proper way to do this is to use a negative voltage regulator, designed for this exact purpose. For instance, the common 7805 +5 V regulator has its complementary version, the 7905 -5 V regulator.

Comment: I don't think the regulator would need to sink any current connected like this. Although as you say, it won't regulate properly with respect to Gnd as it will create around -7 V.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Well, no, it wouldn't, but only because there's no load attached. If there was a load between "-5V" and ground, it would need to sink current.

Comment: Right, I was thinking of loads from -5 to the -12 V rail. It's easy to get confused with contraptions like this.

Comment: OK, I just realized that I would need two independent 12 V supplies with no common ground to use the same LDO. I would then hook up the positive supply side with the ground from the other side Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: @Hansel I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I suspect that won't work either. Ask a new question with a schematic, perhaps? I don't see where having two independent supplies would help.

Comment: I would use two galvanically isolated supplies and use the configuration as shown at the top. Connecting the ground of one of the supplies with the +5 V output of the other supply would work.

Comment: @Hansel No, that would not work. I don't have the time to articulate why right now though.

Comment: @Hearth, sure it will. See above.

Comment: @Hansel Okay, now that you have a diagram I see what you mean. That would work, but it's not ideal.  See bobflux's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first one makes one +5V and one -7V supply, the latter being referenced to -12V and only able to source current. Useless to power something referenced to ground, but.. useful if you had a low-side MOSFET driver on -12V, so that chip has its "ground" on -12V and requires some 5V supply referenced to its "ground". Probably not what you want though.

If the two 12V supplies are galvanically isolated, then the second one will work. It's like taking two isolated 5V power supplies and wiring them in series. However, compared to a positive and negative regulator, it needs 4 extra diodes, and you can't use the +12/-12 for anything else because they're not referenced to a common ground, so they're not +12/-12. Instead, they will be two independent 12V supplies with about 7V between their grounds. So it's not convenient.

Comment: I've added a simulation above, though I am not sure it proves the point for the naysayers. [Edited by a moderator.]